# Generate A Big GridPane with Java FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Hi I'm a newbie in FXML and in general in JavaFX.

As said in the title, I want to create a GridPane with 64+ cells.
My question is:

Do I have to write all the code for those 64+ cells or there is a way (like a for loop) to generate them?

Here is my code. My plan is to have a grid of 8x8 (and maybe more) Grass cells.

Grass Class

```
package auto;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

public class Grass extends Ground{

    public Grass(){
        ground= new Rectangle(50,50,Color.GREEN);
    }   
}
```

Ground Class

```
package auto;

import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;


public abstract class Ground {
    protected Rectangle ground;
}
```

FXML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>

<StackPane   alignment="CENTER"
   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:controller="auto.FXMLDocumentController"
> 
     <Rectangle fx:id="Back" id="Back" height="700" width="500" />
     <VBox id="APP" prefWidth="450" maxWidth="450" minWidth="450"  >
          <StackPane style="-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-width: 2px;">
              <Rectangle id="menu-style" height="50" width="450"/>

              <HBox id="Menu"> 
                 <Button text="Start"/>
                 <Label> Current Cars</Label>
                 <Button text="Add Car"/>  
              </HBox>

          </StackPane>
         <GridPane id="Game" fx:id="Game">
         //8x8 grid of Grass 

         </GridPane>
     </VBox> 
</StackPane>
```

Main Java code

```
package auto;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class RaceGame extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {

       stage.setTitle("Race Game");
       Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
       String css = this.getClass().getResource("RaceGame.css").toExternalForm();
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

EDIT#1

I tried using the controller. The problem is that Grass is not a Node.

```
package auto;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FXMLDocumentController  {

    @FXML
    private GridPane Game;

    public FXMLDocumentController() {
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
               Game.add(new Grass(), i, j);
           }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You could of course use a seperate fxml for the children of the `GridPane` and use 64 `<fx:include>` elements, which could reduce the repetition. However you should ask yourself if it's really worth doing EVERYTHING in fxml or if it's better to fill the `GridPane` from the `initialize` method of the controller. This would most likely be much easier to maintain...

Comment: @fabian In fact I thought about the controller but have no idea how to Implement this.

Comment: You've got another problem: `Game` will not be injected to the controller at the time the constructor runs, but later, which is why you need to move the loop to the `initialize` method. Furthermore if you want to add non-`Node` classes to the `GridPane`, how do you expect this to work with fxml? The same limitations still exist, whether you add the children via fxml or java code: only `Node`s can be added as children of a `GridPane`. Probably there is some way for you to create or access `Node`s corresponding to your `Ground` instances...

Comment: @fabian Ok i moved the loop in the initialize method but now there is the Node problem. I tried:`Ground extends Node ` but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER

I managed the problem in this way:

---

1. Use the Controller to generate the grid and more precisely the `initialize()` method. 
   Unlike the constructor of the FXML controller class, the initialize method can use all  the @FXML referencies because they are loaded after the constructor and before the initialize method.
2. Declare `Ground extends Rectangle` so the grid can accept Ground Objects. Now Ground IS A Node and can be added to the grid.

---

Ground class

```
package auto;

import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public abstract class Ground extends Rectangle{
}
```

Grass class

```
package auto;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Grass extends Ground{

    Grass(){
       this.setWidth(50);
       this.setHeight(50);
       this.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    }      
}
```

FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>

<StackPane   alignment="CENTER"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="auto.FXMLDocumentController"
> 
<Rectangle fx:id="Back" id="Back" height="700" width="500" />
<VBox id="APP" prefWidth="450" maxWidth="450" minWidth="450"  >
    <StackPane style="-fx-border-color: green; -fx-border-width: 2px;">
        <Rectangle id="menu-style" height="50" width="450"/>

        <HBox id="Menu"> 
            <Button text="Start"/>
            <Label> Current Cars</Label>
            <Button text="Add Car"/>  
        </HBox>
    </StackPane>
    <GridPane id="Game" fx:id="Game">


    </GridPane>
</VBox> 
</StackPane>
```

FXML Controller

```
package auto;


import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class FXMLDocumentController  {

    @FXML
    private GridPane Game;

    public void initialize() {
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
               Game.add(new Grass(), i, j);
           }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you seemed to have answered this yourself but I'll leave this here anyways it seems you are over complicating this

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    public Rectangle Back;
    public GridPane Game;

    private void createGrass(){
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                Game.add(new Rectangle(50,50, Color.GREEN), i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        createGrass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, but I have to use the `Grass` class in the declaration. For the rest is perfect